# Bootstrap Popover With Multicolumn Display Not Expanding to Width

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

[Bootply is here](http://www.bootply.com/HgbuHFYwo7)

I'm trying to use a multicolumn display in a bootstrap popover and the content seems to keep trying to fit the popover rather than the other way around.  I've futzed with the width and max-width property to no avail.  The biggest problems are noticeable (in the bootply) on the fieldset legends, where the last one gets cut off, and in the field labels, which are wrapping, rather than the popover getting larger to accomodate them.

Why won't the popover expand?  I used to have another column and I removed it to get more space and instead the popover just shrunk to the new content.

Comment: http://www.bootply.com/SKLpcPWQeD fixed formatting. also, for clarification: you want the popover to **not** have a horizontal scroll bar, and for everything to fit inside it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you do not like that the popover has a column that scrolls off the edge (horizontally). The problem was that you did not put all of the rows and columns inside of a container:

**Code** (data-content for popover):

```
<div class='container-fluid'>
....
</div>
```

**CSS**: Changed `max-width` and removed `width:auto`

```
 .popover {
  max-width: 100%;

  overflow-y:auto;
  z-index:1000;
}
```

[BOOTPLY DEMO](http://www.bootply.com/0auVNPChvH)

[image]

Bootstrap requires [containers](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#overview-container) to wrap the grid system together, otherwise it will not format correctly.

If you want to get rid of the horizontal scroll bar remove the `overflow-y:auto;` CSS. - Thanks Shawn Taylor

Comment: Sorta.  Looking at your bootply, the popover doesn't clip the last fieldset legend but it still isn't expanding so that the labels inside of each column are one-lined (take a look at "Est. Condition").  The popover is still getting it's width from somewhere and that somewhere doesn't seem to be its content

Comment: @ABMagil I reformatted it again, is this what you're looking for? http://www.bootply.com/0auVNPChvH

Comment: Much better.  What was the change you made?  Did you directly set widths on each `<td>`?

Comment: @ABMagil I changed `max width` to `100%` and removed `width:auto` as well as formatted your code correctly. The container was your largest problem.

Comment: Forget my answer, this is better by a mile. Also, if you remove "overflow-y:auto" you get your chevron back and lose the h-scroll bar (it shows up because the chevron ends up within the popover).

Comment: @ShawnTaylor thank you I will include that in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I know this isn't exactly what you've asked ("why won't my popover expand"), but it does solve the overflow issue... just add this to your CSS:

```
.panel-legend{font-size:16px;}
```

Answer (score -1):

I noticed that the `.popover` class is restricted to `max-width:276px;` in the bootstrap.min.css. When you inspect the elements (in Google chrome) you can see this.
I took a screenshot of what i meant.

link to screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/zFpJA.png

If you can remove the max-width restriction you can set the width of `.popover` to a 100%.

I hope this help :)

#### EDIT###

if you change

```
.popover {
    max-width: 100%;

    overflow-y:auto;
    z-index:1000;
}
```

To:

```
.popover {
  max-width: 100%;
  z-index:1000;
}

.row {
   max-width:100%;
}
```

It should work :)

Comment: If you take a look at the bootply provided, you will see that the max-width has been overridden to 800px.  Opening up DevTools will show that the existing popover already has a width larger than 276px